# Using JSON to retrieve data and enter it into an html file

Tags: json

Right now, I am trying to make it so when I click on the button "Retrieve data" all of the "Lorem Ipsum" entries get filled in with the correct data. Such as the Ambient Temperature getting filled in with a temperature stated in another file/location. But I am having no luck as of yet.

```
<!-- begin col-6 -->
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <!-- begin panel -->
        <div class="panel panel-inverse" data-sortable-id="table-basic-1">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-heading-btn">
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-circle btn-default" data-click="panel-expand"><i class="fa fa-expand"></i></a>
                </div>
                <h4 class="panel-title">Default Table</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="table">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Status</b></td>
                            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Server Update</b></td>
                            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-inverse" data-sortable-id="table-basic-1">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-heading-btn">
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-circle btn-default" data-click="panel-expand"><i class="fa fa-expand"></i></a>
                </div>
                <h4 class="panel-title">Default Table</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="table">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Signal Strength</b></td>
                            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Main Power</b></td>
                            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Backup Battery</b></td>
                            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Ambient Temperature</b></td>
                            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end panel -->
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary m-r-5">Retrieve Data</button>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you need to identify the parts of the DOM you need to be able to change them.

Basically, you can do this if you use JQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#btn").click(function() {
      $("#fld_status").text("OK");
      $("#fld_server_update").text("today");
   });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- begin col-6 -->
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <!-- begin panel -->
        <div class="panel panel-inverse" data-sortable-id="table-basic-1">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-heading-btn">
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-circle btn-default" data-click="panel-expand"><i class="fa fa-expand"></i></a>
                </div>
                <h4 class="panel-title">Default Table</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="table">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Status</b></td>
                            <td id="fld_status">Lorem ipsum dolor </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Server Update</b></td>
                            <td id="fld_server_update">Lorem ipsum dolor </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-inverse" data-sortable-id="table-basic-1">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-heading-btn">
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-circle btn-default" data-click="panel-expand"><i class="fa fa-expand"></i></a>
                </div>
                <h4 class="panel-title">Default Table</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="table">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Signal Strength</b></td>
                            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Main Power</b></td>
                            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Backup Battery</b></td>
                            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Ambient Temperature</b></td>
                            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end panel -->
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
                <input id="btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary m-r-5">Retrieve Data</input>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This answered my question!